# I want to check if a user has used a known voucher before

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi there hope you are doing fantastic. I'm developing an ecommerce website using laravel. The problem that i am currenclty facing is that i want to limit the usage of voucher(10OFF) to be used only one time by every user. But am unable to get this task done . I have three tables

- Users Table
- Coupon Table
- Coupon_User Table

Right now if i do this

```
$coupon->users()->exists()
```

it works but the problem is that this if i login with another user's id it still display error that the code has been used whereas the code was used by user of id 1 not by user of id 2

Can anyone help me in achieveing this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just have to add a where clause to your check to filter for only the current user:

```php
$coupon->users()->where('id', Auth::id())->exists();
```